# Error with returning reference to temporary object

Tags: c++

I have a following template function in c++

```
template<class S, class T> const T& safe_retrieve
(vector<T> const& data, vector<S> const& keys, const S& key)
{
    assert(data.size() == keys.size());
    typename vector<S>::const_iterator it = binary_find(keys.begin(), keys.end(), key);
    assert(it != keys.end());
    size_t index = static_cast<size_t>(it - keys.begin());
    return data.at(index);
}
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
 error: returning reference to temporary [-Werror=return-local-addr]
```

I understand the meaning of this error, but I don't see why the reference that I'm returning is temporary.

Comment: Could it be that you're using it with `T=bool`? The template specialization for `std::vector<bool>::at()` doesn't return a "classic" reference. Try returning `typename vector<T>::const_reference` instead of `const T&`.

Comment: That's it! thanks!! It was a vector<bool> and your suggestions fixed it.

Comment: I try with vs2015 and it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to turn my comment into a proper answer:

Your code assumes that `vector<T>::at() const` always returns a `const T&`. However, that is not always the case: The [template specialization for `std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) has a different type of reference (a [proxy for the respective bit in the internal bit vector implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) in lieu of a normal reference, and a plain `bool` value in lieu of a const reference).  In this case, `at()` returns a temporary, which you cannot pass on using a reference.

The solution is to declare your function as follows:

```
template <class S, class T>
typename std::vector<T>::const_reference  // sic!
safe_retrieve(std::vector<T> const& data,
              std::vector<S> const& keys,
              const S& key)
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `data` is a `std::vector<T> const&`, it could be a temporary:

```
safe_retrieve(std::vector<int>{10,20}, std::vector<int>{1,2}, 2);
```

With that use of `safe_retrieve`, a temporary would be returned.

---

### Minimal example

Source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int const& get(std::vector<int> const& data)
{
    return data.at(0);
}

int main() {
    int const& data = get(std::vector<int>{42, 0});
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
}
```

Compilation:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -Werror main.cpp && ./a.out
```

Run:

```
$ ./a.out
0
```

It should be 42, hello UB ;)

Comment: With `std::string` in lieu of `int`, I get a nice seg fault.